# Undefined variable error, but variable is defined

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to get the form values when clicking on the submit button, but when I run this, I get the below error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\mylearning\add_user.php on line 20
```

Here is my code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> I am learning </title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form name="new_user" method="post" action="add_user.php">  
       <input type="text" name="mail"/> <br /> 
        <input type="text" name="name"/><br/> 
        <input type="submit" name="submitbtn"  value="continue"/> 
    </form>
 </body> 
</html>



<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submitbtn"])) 

$mail = isset($_POST['mail']);
$name1 = isset($_POST['name']); echo "Returned value from the function : $name1";  echo "Returned value from the function : $mail"; 

?>
```

Comment: what is on line 20 in `add_user.php`?

Comment: What's on the line on which you are getting error

Comment: does adding value to the input type do help ? like `<input type="text" value="" >` I Suspect $mail is not receiving the typed value

Answer (score 1):

You missed `{ }` of `if` .

Try this way :

```
        <html> 
    <head> 
        <title> I am learning </title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form name="new_user" method="post" action="add_user.php">  
           <input type="text" name="mail"/> <br /> 
            <input type="text" name="name"/><br/> 
            <input type="submit" name="submitbtn"  value="continue"/> 
        </form>
     </body> 
    </html>  
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST["submitbtn"])) 
    {
        $mail = isset($_POST['mail']);
        $name1 = isset($_POST['name']); echo "Returned value from the function : $name1";  echo "Returned value from the function : $mail"; 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: if is not a loop, it is statement.

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya not necessary

Comment: @krupalshah , i know, but if we have multiple line in `if` statement then it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the {}, if you omitt them only the first instruction after the `if` will be executed inside the `if` condition, if you need multiple lines you need to add the curly brackets.

Other notes, you are assigning the value of `isset` to the `$mail` variable, `isset` returns true if the variable exists and it's not null, false otherwise, you could use the ternary operator:

```
$mail = isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail'] : '';
```

That reads, if the post variable is not null use that, otherwise use 'an empty string, the same goes for `$name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST["submitbtn"])){
 $mail = isset($_POST['mail']);
 $name1 = isset($_POST['name']); echo "Returned value from the function : $name1";
 }
```

The code will print **1Returned value from the function : 1** because $mail and $name1 is 1. That's what isset function returns! It checks if you have filled something in those text fields, not what you have filled.

Comment: please do not duplicate answers ...first answer is telling exact same thing